# How to add consumer and producer credentials in a docker file using jwt authentication

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, oauth, sasl, kafkajs

ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {}

The docker is also showing that the token has been verified, but how is autnetication happenng here?

`The below given is my yaml file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.1
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:  
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:5.4.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: 'false'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT, SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL : SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: OAUTHBEARER
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: OAUTHBEARER
      KAFKA_OPTS: '-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      # KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKAJS_NO_PARTITIONER_WARNING: 1
      KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 500000000
      # OAuth Configuration
      OAUTH_WITH_SSL: "false"
      # OAUTH_LOGIN_SERVER : "hydra:4444"
      # OAUTH_LOGIN_ENDPOINT : "/oauth2/token"
      # OAUTH_LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE: "client_credentials"
      # OAUTH_LOGIN_SCOPE: "broker.kafka"
      # OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION : "Basic YnJva2VyLWthZmthOmJyb2tlci1rYWZrYQ=="
      # OAUTH_INTROSPECT_SERVER : "hydra:4445"
      # OAUTH_INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT : "/oauth2/introspect"
      # OAUTH_INTROSPECT_AUTHORIZATION : "Basic YnJva2VyLWthZmthOmJyb2tlci1rYWZrYQ=="
      # CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      # CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      # CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      # CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      # CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    volumes:
      - ./testHelpers/kafka:/etc/kafka
```

`